# Continual Reading Database Table with Spring Batch

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I would like to develop an application which listens a database table and process the data immediately. Batch does not execute for only one time. It listens the table regularly, for example with 10 seconds interval. Whenever new data are inserted in the table, the batch starts the process.

Is it possible to develop such an application with "Spring Batch". If yes, can you please give some advice for it?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Does it work?

Answer (score 0):

This goal can be archived using quartz ; just launch the job every 10 seconds and process, in your step, the new data. I haven't tried myself and can't check now (I'm writing from my mobile) but there are a lot of example on SO.